# Amazon web scraper works only on a country

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

old story, small web scraper to track amazon product prices for personal use. Here the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}

url = "<<my_url>>"

response=requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
target = soup.find('span', {'class':'a-price-whole'})
```

This seems to work for the Italian amazon, while for the German and the Dutch amazon the response of the request does not correspond to the html I see using dev tools and the target is None.

Any idea of what's going on? Any suggestion on how to solve the problem?

Thanks!

I tried to extract information from a webpage, but obtained html via request does not correspond to what I see using dev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the first thing to do was to check how the "not working" parsed webpage looked like, and it looked like a CAPTCHA. In other words, the amazon website "figured out" that I was sending automatic requests from my IP address.

Implementing both random user agents and proxies I managed to pass amazon checks. In particular, this reading was very useful: https://www.zenrows.com/blog/how-to-rotate-proxies-in-python#iterate-over-all-the-proxies